# How can I substitute one command for another temporarily?

Tags: shell-script, path

I'd like to alias sed to gsed, but only while a particular script is running.

I have a script that invokes sed. On the Mac, BSD sed doesn't support the required features, but I don't want to replace it globally with the GNU version.

I can't set an alias in the invoker, as aliases aren't propagated, and I can't set it in a login script as then it will apply globally. The script can't be edited.

I'm posting my current solution, using a nasty symlink/path hack, as an answer, but I'm hoping that someone will come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Runs a command with gsed substituting for sed

set -e

mkdir -p /tmp/temp-path
ln -fs `which gsed` /tmp/temp-path/sed
export PATH=/tmp/temp-path/:$PATH
eval "$@"
```

Comment: I know this is old, but can you explain it a little? What makes this temporary? And does it leave behind that director? Also I guess 4 years later, have you come up with a better way to do it?

Comment: It does leave behind the symlink in tmp, but that’s what tmp is for and the OS will clear it out at some point. The key thing is that the substitution only applies to the evaluation of the command because the revised PATH is only in effect to the eval expression

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to install the GNU versions of utilities in a specific directory, such as `/usr/local` or `/usr/local/gnu`

Then when you wish to use that specific app in a script you would refer to it explicitly as `/usr/local/gnu/bin/sed`

Another option would be to assign a `SED` variable while is exportable.

```
SED=`which gsed`
export SED
```

Thereafter call sed via `${SED}`

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned, the script can't be edited!

Comment: Update your question to include that information, as well as including your current solution which you've included as an answer.